# Can't get response from axios POST request (React)

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I'm trying to get the response header from this axios request:

```
     const res = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_URL_API + "/login", {
                username: userRef.current.value,
                password: passwordRef.current.value,
            }).then(response => console.log(response.headers))
```

The status is 200 and I got 2 responses

"OPTIONS", which his, from what I have read, related to CORS policy

[CHROME response OPTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4X2J.png)

And POST response, with the headers I need (credential, JWT and all)

[CHROME response POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX7gl.png)

Here is my problem: in axios `response` i'm getting the `OPTIONS` headers wish are useless and I don't know how to access the "real" data in `POST`, how do I adress this?

Comment: if you are using `. then()` you should not use `await`

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

In the end it was a backend (Spring) CORS config problem, I had not configured proper headers visibility.

```
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    List<String> allowOrigins = Arrays.asList("*");
    configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(allowOrigins);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(singletonList("*"));
    //Adding following line made the required headers visible in frontend
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Role", "Username"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```